# App is not running properly in One Plus mobile

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-9.0-pie

My app is working fine in all mobiles but in One Plus mobile its not working proper and suddenly mobile gets stuck or in app black screen will come and it will not allow to operate mobile.I am not getting what error is it and it is not report any error.And that mobile configuration is OnePlus6, android version 9,OxygenOS version 9.0.4 and model is ONEPLUS A6000.

Comment: check the error log

Comment: It will not give any error report,when i open app suddenly mobile got stuck and black screen will come and not even to operate mobile till 10 or 15 min only in One Plus mobile.

Comment: check logcat output, there will be something.